# Error starting xfce ubuntu

Tags: boot

It keeps saying error no screen and server error. Please help. I have tried to restart and do it again but it didn't work.

This is what it says on my screen.

```
Fatal server error: no screens found (EE) Please consult the The X.Org 
Foundation support at wiki.x.org for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information. 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). 
Closing log file. /usr/bin/xinit: giving up /usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: 
No such file or directory /usr/bin/xinit: server error Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise
```

Comment: This is what it says on my screen. Fatal server error:
no screens found
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...